# How to Share a Winforms Control and Code Behind Between Different Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, code-behind

I've created a groupbox that is used to populate a list of files and their description. I've also written the code behind for properly adding the files. Is it possible to share the code behind and UI so that it can be used in other forms without having to rewrite the code? I know that you can create a base form, that contains the winforms control you want to share. That way you can have your new form you inherit from the base class. But I'm not looking to implement it this way.

Comment: A GroupBox is a pretty miserable control to ever list anything.  Deriving your own class from an existing control, like ListBox or ListView, is a very basic strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, it can be. Create a [`User Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) for your GroupBox and use the same in whichever form you want. User controls are meant for that purpose to increase code re-usability.

In case, you think the same GroupBox control can be used in other project as well then you should consider building it as [`Custom Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t(v=vs.100).aspx)